# SpringBoot java Collection annotation for Swagger

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, spring-rest

I have a problem with annotations and generating documentation (spring-boot, springfox-swagger2).

What should be a proper annotation for String Collection in my TechnologyDTO?

Does swagger support java.util.Collection?

---

After generation I have:

**Model schema:**

```
{
    "technologies": {},
    "userGUID": "string"
}
```

**Model:**

```
TechnologyDTO {
    technologies (Collection«string»): User main technology names,
    userGUID (string): User guid
}

Collection«string» {
}
```

**My TechnologyDTO:**

```
public class TechnologyDTO {
    private final String userGUID;
    private final Collection<String> technologies;

    public TechnologyDTO(String userGUID, Collection<String> technologies) {
        this.userGUID = userGUID;
        this.technologies = technologies;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "User guid", dataType="string", required = true)
    public String getUserGUID() {
        return userGUID;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "User main technology names", required = true)
    public Collection<String> getTechnologies() {
        return technologies;
    }

    public static TechnologyDTO createEmptyDTO() {
        return new TechnologyDTO(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this @Cynamon2016?